# Table to another table as a wordlist in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to transfer content and columns to train table from tf1 table. Datas can be converted to wordlist.
**But tf1 table must transfer to 0. line of train table because it belongs there (it's analysis).**

[train table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIsus.png)

[tf1 table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHSwK.png)

Independently of these, how can I change an item of 'duyuru' line?

```
['duyuru'][0]='hi'
```

is not working...

Answer (score 0):

you can change it this way:

train.at[0, "duyuru"] = "hi"